Does the “wave” solution contain every solution to the Maxwell’s equations?

I was thinking that we obviously do have wave solutions to the Maxwell equations. We might have some other solutions, such as $E = 0$ and $B = 0$, which are the same as the wave solutions with the amplitudes set to zero. We can also check the Electrostatic case, where $\textrm{Curl} \!\left( E \right) = 0$ and $B = 0$, which is also the wave solution with the magnetic field amplitude set to zero. We do have that for the Magnetostatic case as well. Can we generally say that every “physical” solution to Maxwell’s equations is actually “included” in the wave solution, where the different parameters of the wave change?

The wave solution, as is usually meant, is only for the case of zero charge density and zero current density. As such, it can never cover the case of non-zero densities in either charge or current or both.

All free space solutions to Maxwell's equations are indeed also solutions to the electromagnetic wave equation. This is because the wave equation is deduced directly from Maxwell's equations. An electrostatic or magnetostatic solution in free space is simply a Laplacian vector field, and therefore they correctly follow the "wave" equation $\nabla^2 \mathbf{E}=0$ (same for $\mathbf{B}$).
For solutions besides free space, it's typical to write them in terms of the vector and scalar potentials, and the solutions to those equations are the well known retarded potentials that determine the electromagnetic field for each point in space and time.
